# how to mapping through nested multi dimensional array and convert into new response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello friends let say i have nested data below

```
const payload = [
    {
      title: "ADDITIONAL",
      data: [
        {
          documentCategory: "ADDITIONAL",
          documentCode: "CUSTOMER_CLAIM_FORM",
          documentKey:
            "customer/9fdf7ca8-4251-41c8-9116-6d006fa64aea/800123000004054/LIFESAVER_DEATH/LIFESAVER_DEATH_CUSTOMER_CLAIM_FORM_ca2b0204-b8c4-42f7-b059-580818789a64.jpg"
        },
        {
          documentCategory: "ADDITIONAL",
          documentCode: "POWER_OF_ATTORNEY",
          documentKey:
            "customer/9fdf7ca8-4251-41c8-9116-6d006fa64aea/800123000004054/LIFESAVER_DEATH/LIFESAVER_DEATH_POWER_OF_ATTORNEY_6de88371-c666-4ce5-87f2-8aedf778f4c4.jpg"
        },
        {
          documentCategory: "ADDITIONAL",
          documentCode: "POLICE_RECORD",
          documentKey:
            "customer/9fdf7ca8-4251-41c8-9116-6d006fa64aea/800123000004054/LIFESAVER_DEATH/LIFESAVER_DEATH_POLICE_RECORD_15d989de-9cfb-4574-8451-92f445177331.jpg"
        }
      ],
      chevronFlag: true
    },
...
]
```

ive try several ways like below

```
  for (let i = 0; i < payload.length; i++) {
    const element = payload[i].data.map((item) => {
      return item;
    });
    console.log(element);
  }
```

and i got this result for each new obj for each properties in array

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNKMU.png)

my goals is

```
const newObj = {
documentCode: "CUSTOMER_CLAIM_FORM"
documentKey: "customer/9fdf7ca8-4251-41c8-9116-6d006fa64aea/800123000004054/LIFESAVER_DEATH/LIFESAVER_DEATH_CUSTOMER_CLAIM_FORM_ca2b0204-b8c4-42f7-b059-580818789a64.jpg",
documentCode: "POWER_OF_ATTORNEY"
documentKey: "customer/9fdf7ca8-4251-41c8-9116-6d006fa64aea/800123000004054/LIFESAVER_DEATH/LIFESAVER_DEATH_POWER_OF_ATTORNEY_6de88371-c666-4ce5-87f2-8aedf778f4c4.jpg",
...
}
```

please help me to understand.. thank you so much

Comment: Your new object (`newObj`) would have duplicate keys (which wouldn't work). Is there another structure that would work for you?

Comment: have duplicated key? can you explain more detail, please?  is there any idea or approach to make it each array merge in oneobject like this 
`
const newObj = {
documentCode: "CUSTOMER_CLAIM_FORM"
documentKey: "customer/9fdf7c-4251-41c8-9116-6d006fa64aea/8001230004054/LIFESAVER_DEATH/LIFESAVER_DEATH_CUSTOMER_CLAIM_FORM_ca2-b0518789a64.jpg",
documentCode: "POWER_OF_ATTORNEY"
documentKey: "customer/9fdf7ca8-4251-41ca-6d006fa64aea/800123000004054/LIFESAVER_DEATH/LIFESAVER_DEATH_POWER_OF_ATTORNEY_6de8837.jpg",
...
}
`

im currently stil struggle andl try to find best approach, thanks btw

Comment: You cannot have an object that has duplicate keys, such as stated in your goal. For example `let newObj = { a: 1, b: 2, a: 1 }` will not work because `a` is being used twice, object keys `a, b, a` must be unique. Otherwise you will keep overwriting `a`

Comment: If you tell us how do you plan to consume that data, we might advise valid data structure suitable to your needs.

Comment: @YevhenHorbunkov actually from this case i need to wrap newObj for payload  needs for my BE sevice :/ somehow i kinda stuck and struggling to wrap into newObj

Comment: If your backend is expected to store partially content of the `payload.data` array, you may keep it as array: `[{documentCode:'foo", documentKey: 'bar'}, {documentCode: 'baz', documentKey: 'qux'} ..]`. In order to achieve that you may simply do `payload.data.map(({documentCode, documentKey}) => ({documentCode, documentKey}))`.

Comment: If, for some reason, object is more preferrable,and `documentCode` is guaranteed to be unique, you may use it as a property name with `documentKey` as a property value: `payload.data.reduce((acc, {documentCode, documentKey}) => (acc[documentCode]=documentKey, acc), {})`

Answer (score 2):

You can only have unique keys inside an object. What do you think about using the `documentCode` values as keys of `newObj`?

```
  let newObj = {};
  for ({data} of payload) {
    for (item of data) {
      newObj[item.documentCode] = item.documentKey;
    }
  }
  console.log(newObj);
```

response:

```
{
  "CUSTOMER_CLAIM_FORM": "customer/9fdf7ca8-4251-41c8-9116-6d006fa64aea/800123000004054/LIFESAVER_DEATH/LIFESAVER_DEATH_CUSTOMER_CLAIM_FORM_ca2b0204-b8c4-42f7-b059-580818789a64.jpg",
  "POWER_OF_ATTORNEY": "customer/9fdf7ca8-4251-41c8-9116-6d006fa64aea/800123000004054/LIFESAVER_DEATH/LIFESAVER_DEATH_POWER_OF_ATTORNEY_6de88371-c666-4ce5-87f2-8aedf778f4c4.jpg",
  "POLICE_RECORD": "customer/9fdf7ca8-4251-41c8-9116-6d006fa64aea/800123000004054/LIFESAVER_DEATH/LIFESAVER_DEATH_POLICE_RECORD_15d989de-9cfb-4574-8451-92f445177331.jpg"
}
```

Comment: can it be more simpler?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your problem correctly, all you need to do is to get the answer in this format:

```json
[
   {
     "CUSTOMER_CLAIM_FORM": "SOMETHING",
     "POWER_OF_ATTORNEY": "SOMETHING",
     "POLICE_RECORD": "SOMETHING"
   },
   ...
]
```

The array has been used as your payload is an array, and it will have more objects containing the **data** array.

**Solution**

```js
let finalResponse = [];
payload.map(payloadItem => {
  let myObject = {}

  payloadItem.data.map(data => {
    myObject[data.documentCode] = data.documentKey;
    
    return null;
  });

  finalResponse.push(myObject);

  return null;
});

// No compulsion of using JSON.stringify here
console.log(JSON.stringify(finalResponse));
```

**Response**

```json
[
  {
    "CUSTOMER_CLAIM_FORM":"customer/9fdf7ca8-4251-41c8-9116-6d006fa64aea/800123000004054/LIFESAVER_DEATH/LIFESAVER_DEATH_CUSTOMER_CLAIM_FORM_ca2b0204-b8c4-42f7-b059-580818789a64.jpg",
    "POWER_OF_ATTORNEY":"customer/9fdf7ca8-4251-41c8-9116-6d006fa64aea/800123000004054/LIFESAVER_DEATH/LIFESAVER_DEATH_POWER_OF_ATTORNEY_6de88371-c666-4ce5-87f2-8aedf778f4c4.jpg",
    "POLICE_RECORD":"customer/9fdf7ca8-4251-41c8-9116-6d006fa64aea/800123000004054/LIFESAVER_DEATH/LIFESAVER_DEATH_POLICE_RECORD_15d989de-9cfb-4574-8451-92f445177331.jpg"
  }
]
```

As your response grows, it will keep on adding more data to it, and you will see the change as the data changes.